# Find all values in dataframe not containing certain values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

Let's say I have a pandas dataframe with cities and names.
Of course each city will have many names, something like:

```
Chicago   John
Chicago   Mary
Chicago   Jane
```

I realise that I have 1000 distinct cities, but when I groupby name and count how many cities are associated to John, I only see 998.
How do I find what cities do not have any "John" in them?

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
df.groupby('cities').filter(lambda x : (x['name']!='John').all())
```

Comment: And then just add `['City'].unique()` to the end to get an array of the unique cities.

Answer (score 1):

Try `groupby` and `query`:

```
df = df.groupby('city')['names'].value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0)
#here you can replace whatever name you like to check
df.query("John==0").index
```

Comment: I am getting the error: the label [False] is not in the [index]

Comment: @user Can you provide the example that is having error?

Comment: The query part is giving an error. I was able to do: df2 = df["John"], then df2[df2==0].index and that works.